# iOS loading a image in UIImageView is not showing

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm trying to load a background image programmatically but image is not displaying. Here is my code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
        UIImage *backGroundImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        self.backGroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backGroundImage];
        self.backGroundView.hidden = NO;

    }
    return self;
}
```

If print the console the UIImageView:

```
po _backGroundView
<UIImageView: 0x15d40cf0; frame = (0 0; 568 320); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x15d41fb0>>
```

Any of you knows why the image is not loading on the screen?

Comment: Is `self.backGroundView` being added to the view hierarchy?

Comment: Are you using Storyboards? Is the filePath valid? Have you tried to load with [UIImage imageNamed:@"xxx"]; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting the existing backgroundView with a new one - just set the image on the existing one (created automatically when the nib is loaded).

```
self.backGroundView.image = backGroundImage;
```

The way the code is at the moment, you replace the nib-created view with a new one, which isn't then added to the viewController.view. It doesn't show up - the existing view will still be there, in the view hierarchy - but won't be attached to the property - so the image change won't affect it...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the code related to `self.backGroundView` from `initWithNibName:bundle:` and add it to `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *backGroundImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    self.backGroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backGroundImage];
    self.backGroundView.hidden = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:self.backGroundView];
}
```